# IBM MQ - java api - Get all channel names

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I try to get all channel names by connecting to a server connection channel using java api. I set permission to all channels with the following command.

```
setmqaut -m local -t channel -n SYSTEM.** -p test +all
```

The java code,

```
pcfMessageAgent = new PCFMessageAgent(host, port, channelName);
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL);
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "*");
try {
    queueResponses = pcfMessageAgent.send(request);
```

But I get 2035 error code with the below logs and I am unable see `SYSTEM.DEF.CLNTCONN` on explorer and unable to set the permission with the setmqaut command,

```
AMQ8077: Entity 'test@mysystem' has insufficient authority to access
object 'SYSTEM.DEF.CLNTCONN'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: dsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `CLNTCONN` channels are a different object type, they are of type `clntconn`, all other channels types are included in type `channel`.

If you wanted to provide the same permission you would use:

```
setmqaut -m local -t clntconn -n SYSTEM.** -p test +all
```

See my answer to your question "[IBM MQ - Permissions - Read perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754974/ibm-mq-permissions-read-perspective/43765775#43765775)" for more detail on how to set read only permissions.